# Why does this function not work as expected?

Tags: clojure

Why does this function not work as expected?

```
(defn my-juxt
  [& fns]
  (if (= 1 (count fns))
    (fn [& a] (list (apply (first fns) a)))
    (fn [& a]
      (cons (apply (first fns) a) ((my-juxt (rest fns)) a)))))
```

Note: This works -

```
(defn new-juxt
  [& fns]
  (fn [& a]
    (map #(apply % a) fns)))
```

Comment: Hope the `fns` is not long list to blow the stack as you are not using tail recursion :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in how varargs are used. `my-juxt` has params `[& fns]` while it's  given `[fns]` in the last string. The same is with the function it returns as a result: it expects `[& a]` while provided `[a]`.

The code below will work (please note two extra `apply`'s there)

```
(defn my-juxt
  [& fns]
  (if (= 1 (count fns))
    (fn [& a] (list (apply (first fns) a)))
    (fn [& a]
      (cons (apply (first fns) a) 
            (apply (apply my-juxt (rest fns)) a)))))
```